# Unsigned char does not show up in printf when i put it in a char array

Tags: c, string, casting

I am trying to make a char array put together of unsigned char variables that I pass into a function like shown:

```
int swap(unsigned char first, unsigned char second){

    printf("First: %u",first);

    char result[4];
    result[0] = first;
    result[1] = '0';
    result[2] = '0';
    result[3] = '\0';
    printf("\nResult: %s", result);

    return 0;
}
```

In this case if I pass in '2' to first (the first prints statements works fine), but the second print statements does not print out '200'. I tried casting first as a char such as (char)first in the assignment statement but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Why is the function named `swap()`? It doesn't swap anything ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using an int and '2' in char is not a visible character.  You need to add 48 to the value to get the character.

```
result[0] = first + 48;
```

You need to look at the ASCII table which maps numbers to characters:
http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

The character representation of numbers start at 48 which is the character (0).  If you look at the table the character for 2 which is what you were putting is not defined as a printed character.  Which is why it wasn't working.

Comment: 50 is the equivalent of 0? Can you explain further thanks for the response

Comment: @user3037172: Because of the ascii table.  50 is the letter 2.  54 is the letter 6...